# Click Map Image and Display Values

Tags: php, javascript, variables, dictionary, click

Problem:
I have a map of the United States and have created hotspots on the map and I need to display certain values below the map based on the hotspot that they click.

```
example: <area shape="poly" coords="575,129,590,126" id="location1" href="" />
```

The values that will be displayed below are Name, Title, Phone, and Email and there might be multiple people that come up based on where they are assigned.

```
Example:
Joe Smith is assigned to California, Nevada, and Washington
John Conner is assigned to Nevada, and Washington
```

When someone clicks the hotspot for California, only Joe Smith's info will come up below the map.  When someone clicks on the hotspot for Nevada, both Joe and John's info will come up below the map.

Im hoping this can be in Javascript or PHP as I am embedding it on a Wordpress page.  Thanks!

Comment: well, are you asking for a solution, or are you looking for someone to write the code for you ? because here is just for coding problems

Comment: Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what to ask and how to ask on this site. As it stands, your question doesn't really fit here as it isn't asking anything specific. A little editing on your part should fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to use jquery. When the user clicks the area it unhides (hides previous) or writes the html in an element.

Sample JQUERY

```
$('#location').click(function() {
   $('#someElement').html('NAME, Address, Phone');
});
```

Comment: Correction: `html()` instead of `innerHTML()`.

Comment: Thank you was thinking in the old javascript dom

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Hakim, sorry im as beginner as they get and am still getting used to this.  I appreciate any help.  =)